# React/Redux controlled input with validation

Tags: reactjs, redux

Lets imagine we want an input for a "product" (stored in redux) price value.

I'm struggle to come up with the best way to handle input constraints.  For simplicity, lets just focus on the constraint that `product.price` cannot be empty.

It seems like the 2 options are:

---

### 1: Controlled

**Implementation:** The input value is bound to `product.price`. On change dispatches the `changePrice()` action.

The main issue here is that if we want to prevent an empty price from entering the product store, we essentially block the user from clearing the input field.  This isn't ideal as it makes it very hard to change the first digit of the number (you have to select it and replace it)!

### 2: Using `defaultValue`

**Implementation:** We set the price initially using input `defaultValue`, that allows us to control when we want to actually dispatch `changePrice()` actions and we can do validation handling in the `onChange` handler.

This works well, unless the `product.price` is ever updated from somewhere other than the input change event (for example, an `applyDiscount` action).  Since `defaultValue` doesn't cause rerenders, the `product.price` and the input are now out of sync!

---

**So what am I missing?**

There must be a simple & elegant solution to this problem but I just can't seem to find it!

Comment: you could check and validate `onBlur` instead of `onChange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I've figure out a decent solution.  Basically I needed to:

---

1. Create separate component that can control the input with local state.
2. Pass an onChange handler into the props that I can use to dispatch my `changePrice` action conditionally
3. Use `componentWillReceiveProps` to keep the local value state in sync with the redux store

---

### Code (simplified and in typescript):

```
interface INumberInputProps {
  value: number;
  onChange: (val: number) => void;
}

interface INumberInputState {
  value: number;
}

export class NumberInput extends React.Component<INumberInputProps, INumberInputState> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: props.value};
  }

  public handleChange = (value: number) => {
    this.setState({value});
    this.props.onChange(value);
  }

  //keeps local state in sync with redux store
  public componentWillReceiveProps(props: INumberInputProps){
    if (props.value !== this.state.value) {
      this.setState({value: props.value});
    }
  }

  public render() {
    return <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  }
}
```

In my Product Component:

```
  ...
  //conditionally dispatch action if meets valadations
  public handlePriceChange = (price: number) => {
    if (price < this.props.product.standardPrice &&
      price > this.props.product.preferredPrice &&
      !isNaN(price) &&
      lineItem.price !== price){
        this.props.dispatch(updatePrice(this.props.product, price));
    }
  }

  public render() {
     return <NumberInput value={this.props.product.price} onChange={this.handlePriceChange} />
  }
```

...

Answer (score 2):

What I have done in the past is to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) and [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) to solve input constraints/validation using controlled inputs.

In general I like to have one update action that will handle all the field updating. So for example if you have two inputs for a form, it would looks something like this:

```
render() {
  const { product, updateProduct } = this.props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        value={product.name}
        onChange={() => updateProduct({...product, name: e.target.value})}
      />
      <input 
        value={product.price}
        onChange={() => updateProduct({...product, price: e.target.value})}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Having one function/action here simplifies my forms a great deal. The updateProject action would then be a thunk action that handles side effects. Here is our Joi Schema(based off your one requirement) and updateProduct Action mentioned above. As a side note, I also tend to just let the user make the mistake. So if they don't enter anything for price I would just make the submit button inactive or something, but still store away null/empty string in the redux store.

```
const projectSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  name: Joi.number().string(),
  price: Joi.integer().required(), // price is a required integer. so null, "", and undefined would throw an error.
});

const updateProduct = (product) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) {
    Joi.validate(product, productSchema, {}, (err, product) => {
      if (err) {
        // flip/dispatch some view state related flag and pass error message to view and disable form submission;
      }

    });
    dispatch(update(product)); // go ahead and let the user make the mistake, but disable submission
  }
}
```

I stopped using uncontrolled inputs, simply because I like to capture the entire state of an application. I have very little local component state in my projects. Keep in mind this is sudo code and probably won't work if directly copy pasted. Hope it helps.

Comment: Another side note: Joi isn't required here. You can do any sort of checking and send off dispatches accordingly.

Comment: I get the numerous benefits of being able to capture the entire state, but I'm pretty adamant on protecting the store from invalid values.   Mainly because if I don't, then I have to add checks in every selector/component that references it (for example if you had a summary or save component).

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I usually only use the value here in this one "creatingProduct" reducer for creation purposes only. Then I have another reducer that holds the state of a "current" product or "list" of products that is hydrated via a api/db. So if you think about the file structure I would have a Product Folder with an index that combines the Reducers creating, list, current, etc. Keeps it clean and the reducers small.

Comment: nice, so one state is basically just the UI state and the you have the BL state separate.  Single action can can update both, but you can be selective with the BL side.

Answer (score 1):

What i would do in this case is to validate the input `onBlur` instead of `onChange`.

For example consider these validations in the flowing snippet:

1. The input can't be empty.
2. The input should not contain "foo".

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myVal: '',
      error: ''
    }
  }

  setError = error => {
    this.setState({ error });
  }

  onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ myVal: value })
  }

  validateInput = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    let nextError = '';
    if (!value.trim() || value.length < 1) {
      nextError = ("Input cannot be empty!")
    } else if (~value.indexOf("foo")) {
      nextError = ('foo is not alowed!');
    }

    this.setError(nextError);
  }

  render() {
    const { myVal, error } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={myVal} onChange={this.onChange} onBlur={this.validateInput} />
        {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**

As a followup to your comments.

To make this solution more generic, i would pass the component a predicate function as a prop, only when the function will return a valid result i would call the `onChange` that passed from the parent or whatever method you pass that updating the store.

This way you can reuse this pattern in other components and places on your app (or even other projects).

Comment: I think this approach is closer to what I need, but it doesn't take into account that the value is coming from a redux store that I don't want to update unless the value is valid.  I think what I need to do is break out a component similar to this and control the state locally.  Then have an onChange prop that I can pass in and use to set the redux state.

Comment: using a local state for these kind of validations is fair enough. my rule of thumb regarding storing objects in `redux` store (or lifting the state up in general) is ask my self a question: "_does other parts of my app should know about this value?_" if the answer is no, then local state it is.

Comment: ya, I actually just got it working.  The key was to use `componentWillReceiveProps` to keep the local state in sync with the redux store.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NSjonas please accept the answers if you think it was helpful for your solution